# Displaying a series of divs - 3 divs per line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 to display contact details of users in a website.

I thought that using the bootstrap css class **col-md-4** to allow 3 contact details per line would display the contact details correctly, but I have got this wrong as the display is not what I anticipated.

I have written the html code so that only the entered contact details should be displayed. The user can enter between 1 and 6 contact details. A maximum of three contact details are displayed over each line (using the bootstrap css class col-md-4).

When the user enters 3 contact details the display is as follows (which is what I require):

[image]

However, when the user enters a 4th contact detail, the 4th contact detail is placed under the 3rd contact detail, but should be placed under the 1st contact detail. Here is a visual display of the error:

[image]

**I am certain that this is a simple error I have made, but I cannot fix it. I have searched SO & Google, but could not find a solution, so I have posted this thread to find out how I can solve this issue.**

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="live_preview_standard_nac_contactContainer" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
    <div class="row">
        {{ #if contact_details_phone }}
            <div class="col-md-4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
                <i class="fa fa-phone icon_size20 icon_padding"></i>{{ contact_details_phone }}
            </div>
        {{ /if }}

        {{ #if contact_details_mobile_phone }}
            <div class="col-md-4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
                <i class="fa fa-tablet icon_size24 icon_padding"></i>{{ contact_details_mobile_phone }}
            </div>
        {{ /if }}

        {{ #if contact_details_email_address }}
            <div class="col-md-4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope icon_size20 icon_padding"></i>{{ contact_details_email_address }}
            </div>
        {{ /if }}

        {{ #if contact_details_linkedin_address }}
            <div class="col-md-4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin icon_size20 icon_padding"></i><span class="btu-link">{{ contact_details_linkedin_address }}</span>
            </div>
        {{ /if }}

        {{ #if contact_details_facebook_address }}
            <div class="col-md-4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook icon_size20 icon_padding"></i><span class="btu-link">{{ contact_details_facebook_address }}</span>
            </div>
        {{ /if }}

        {{ #if contact_details_twitter_address }}
            <div class="col-md-4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter icon_size20 icon_padding"></i><span class="btu-link">{{ contact_details_twitter_address }}</span>
            </div>
        {{ /if }}
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.live_preview_standard_nac_contactContainer {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.icon_size20 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
}

.icon_size24 {
    font-size: 24px !important;
}

.icon_padding {
    padding-right: 6px;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should wrap your col-md-4's with a <div class="row">#all cols here#</div>. See what happens then. Also I would use divs instead of span when using the bootstrap grid.

Comment: agree with @BastianW

Comment: I will not write a answer because I don't really know how it works and I would not be able to explain, but in this case I always use Bootstrap CSS component `<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>`, where `lg` is the size yours elements behave weird (so if it only happens on `xs` size, replace `lg` by `xs`). Just put this line before the element that is not at his proper location and it might fix the problem.

Comment: @BastianW, I have replaced spans with divs and encapsulated the divs in a row. There was no change to the display. I have changed the html code in the OP.

Comment: like @BastianW told you, first major mistake.. using an inline-element as a block element. second.. second if you use the gird use it correct (you have no rows!):
1: http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/ 2: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Zeratops, this does not work for me.

Comment: yeah like Bastian said, or you can put an div with style "clear:both" after col 3th

Comment: There is a problem with the font-size. If you change: fa fa-tablet icon_size20 icon_padding to "fa fa-tablet icon_size20 icon_padding" it works. But I have no answer yet, why it behaves like that.

Comment: BastianW, thanks for the comment. Changing the font size down appears to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Source: [>link<](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

> So, to create the layout you want, create a container (). Next, create a row (). Then, add
>   the desired number of columns (tags with appropriate .col-*-*
>   classes). Note that numbers in .col-*-* should always add up to 12 for
>   each row.

Html example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```